# How can i add the image to the bootstrap popover?

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to add the image to the bootstrap popover, but i am not able to get the image.instead it is showing the html.how can i solve this?

```
<img class="filter-icon" src="images/filter-icon.png" class="filter-icon" data-toggle="popover" data-content="<img src='images/club.png'>" popover>

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover();   
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Markup:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var image = '<img src="https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/examples/api/idle/idle_simple/sample-128.png">';
  $('#popover').popover({
    placement: 'bottom',
    content: image,
    html: true
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.0-rc2/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap JS -->
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.0-rc2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<a id="popover" class="btn" rel="popover" data-content="" title="Popover with image">Popover button</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: Add a parameter "html":true

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover({
      html:true
   });   
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify html option to true, try this way :

```
$('[data-toggle="popover"]').({ html:true });​​​
```

Answer (score 0):

This method is for adding images through the data-content attribute **only** using *Bootstrap 4 or higher*.
https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/270085/

Using an HTML button, the default behavior toggles the popover when the button is *pressed* or *clicked*.

```
<button type="button" class="btn pl-2" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-html="true" title="Popover Title" data-content="<img src='https://dummyimage.com/100x100/cccccc/333333.png'/>">Image popover</button>
```

Using an HTML anchor, the default behavior works when the anchor receives *focus*, and dismissed once it loses *focus*.

```
<a tabindex="0" class="btn pl-2" role="button" data-trigger="focus" data-container="body"  data-toggle="popover" data-html="true" title="Popover Title" data-content="<img src='https://dummyimage.com/100x100/cccccc/333333.png'/>">Dismissible popover</a>
```

🙂 [documention](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/popovers/#options)